# Multi Vendor Flutter

Tags: flutter, apk, vendor

I want to make an Flutter application through this application. You can choose a specific theme and make several modifications to it to suit you, but when you are finished, you can make an APK version of this theme from within the application itself. The question is how can I do the APK process from within the application itself to lead me to another separate application About the original app

Comment: so you want to convert an application to flutter application?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is passing all the related details to a backend server and let the server build the APK instead. The user can download the APK once it is ready.